# C# File - Read files from desktop and write them to a specific file

Tags: c#, file-io

I created a `System.Timers.Timer` object with an interval of 5000 ms. On the `Elapsed` event of this timer, I'm searching the new PDF files which appeared on Desktop. If there are new PDF files, I add those to the specific file, but my program catch this error: **The process cannot acces the file 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\StartupFiles.dat' because it is being used by another process**.
Here is my code:

```
    private readonly string fileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\StartupFiles.dat";
    private readonly string sourceDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); 

    void timerCheck_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
                File.Create(fileName);

            string[] PDFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.pdf", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            bool exist;
            string addText = string.Empty;

            foreach (string s in PDFiles) // Check the files from the desktop with the files from the fileName variabile folder
            {
                exist = false;
                foreach (string c in textFile)
                {
                    if (string.Compare(s, c) == 0)
                    {
                        exist = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!exist)
                {
                    addText += s + '\n';                        
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(addText)) // If a new PDF appeard on the desktop, save it to file
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName))
                {
                    sw.Write(addText);
                }    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Maybe I have to set a little delay between `ReadAllLines` and `File.AppendText` ?

Comment: What is the other process that's accessing the file?  Is this code trying to access the file on a timer elapsed event while its previous elapsed event is still accessing it?

Comment: I don't know which is the other process, this is the only place where I'm accessing this file...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3189617/1226915 so try using a `FileStream` instead of `File.ReadAllLines()` here

Comment: The Problem is this line, 

string[] textFile = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

Just after the moment you have created this file, you are trying to read it

Comment: Show me, please, an working example.

Answer (score 0):

@charqus, This should Work

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
   File.Create(fileName).Dispose();

string[] PDFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.pdf",    SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
List<String> fileList = new List<String>();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
       fileList.Add(r.ReadString());
    }
}

string[] textFile = fileList.ToArray();
```

Calling the Dispose method ensures that all the resources are properly released.